# Equality constrainsts handling in Evolutionary multiobjective algorithms

Tags: constraints, mathematical-optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I am working on a problem which has two linear constraints including one equality constraint. I am using SPEA2 algorithm. The constraints are given below.

I have tried penalty function approach but had difficulty in selecting parameters. Secondly, I have used constrained dominance relation approach but again could not get feasible solutions. Please advise...

[image: Constraints]

Comment: Please format your answer in a manner that does not incorporate images; image hosts are not reliable, and by the time someone else struggles with a similar question, the host might go down, rendering your question and future answers out of context.

In addition, it is not clear what is being asked and what exactly you have tried.

Comment: A standard trick is to get rid of one variable (say `p(N)`) and then calculate: `P(N) := 1 - [p(1)+..+p(N-1)]`. If `p(N)` is outside `[0,1]` then add penalty.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I have in fact tried similar strategy  where we replace one variable by rewriting it in terms of others using equality (as you suggested) and also got rid of the equality constraint.  I did not apply penalty instead I applied modified constraint  as  0≤ p1+p2+..+pn-1 ≤ 1. To implement this I converted it to two inequalities like -(p1+p2+..+pn-1)  ≤ 0 and p1+p2+..+pn-1 ≤ 1. But I was still unable to get feasible solution. If you can refer some material about your suggested approach, I shall be grateful. Please have a look on my approach also if did it correctly.

Comment: Actually with probabilities it may be better to just generate `p(1)..p(N)` between `[0,1]` and then normalize. I.e. calculate `S=sum p(i)` and then do `p(i):=p(i)/S`.